# C++ - Upper half border is not visible for EDITTEXT component

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

In my C++ MFC application, there are three `EDITTEXT` components and its configuration in .rc file is almost same:

```
EDITTEXT        IDC_FIRSTFILE,66,338,357,12,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
EDITTEXT        IDC_SECONDFILE,66,356,357,13,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
EDITTEXT        IDC_THIRDFILE,66,375,357,13,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
```

But `IDC_SECONDFILE` texteditor upper half border is not visible:
[image: HalfBorderVisibleScreenshot]

When I click in that text editor it shown like :
[image: TextEditorAfterClicking]

Could anyone please help me with this as I am new to develope MFC applications.

Comment: Why not show the whole RC for the dialog? And the whole screen grab of the dialog? I ask because I can see cropped text in the first image ...

Comment: Likely obscured by another control. Check controls' coordinates and dimensions for overlapping. Also check for the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` style.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Exactly. This is why I suggested he show the whole RC for the dialog in question and not just a snippet.

Comment: Thank you so much both of you, I found out that overlapping component there which was not visible. Now I have moved that component to other location and things seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by finding overlapping component as per @ConstantineGeorgiou comment.
We can move that component to different place if it is not required there or we can delete if it is not used anywhere.

Comment: This answer is useful only to those that can see the full resource definition statement. Since the question doesn't provide a [mcve], neither Q nor A are generally useful.